# rails facebook conditional not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, conditional-statements, koala-gem

I am trying to do what this [guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJ19ie3gHTM) did. However I am not able to see the option to post to facebook even after the user has selected yes.

Here is the method in my user model that is supposed to have the koala gem check and see if the user has selected yes to publish_actions.

```html
def verify_permissions
    p = self.facebook.get_connection("me", "permissions")
    pf = p.first
    pf["publish_actions"]
end
```

Here is the conditional in my view.

```html
<% if current_user.verify_permissions == 1 %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :post_on_facebook %>
    <%= f.check_box :post_on_facebook, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```